# I am getting an error- Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined

Tags: jquery, asp.net

While fetching the data from the web api into a table, i am getting an error that Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'indexOf' of undefined. The web api i have checked, its returning the data.

```
$("#divTable").empty();

$('#divTable').GenerateTable({
     tableID: "datatable1",
     //order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
     sourceDataUrl: ApiPath + "Dashboard/GetRegulatoryTable?Type=" + type + "&Subject=" + subject + "&Month=" + month + "&Year=" + year,
     autoColHeader: {
         enable: "false",
         colHead: ["Update ID", "Month", "Year", "Subject", "Description", "Document Path", "Created By", "Created Date"]
     },
     disableColindex: "[]",
});

if ($("#datatable1").html().indexOf("No data available", 1) > 1) { //here its throwing an error
    swal("", "No Data Available", "warning");
    $("#divTable").empty();
}
else {
    $(".cutsdata").DataTable();

    $('#btnDownload').show();
}
```

Comment: Then it would appear that `$("#datatable1").html()` is undefined.  *Should it* be defined?  Does that element exist?

Comment: sorry its a jquery table : <script src="../newassets/plugins/datatables/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>

Comment: @Prakash: Look, the error is pretty clear.  That element isn't found on your page.  Unless you can demonstrate otherwise, that's the explanation to the problem.

Comment: Thank you everyone for your co-operation.

Comment: Did that answer help @Prakash ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#divTable').GenerateTable({
     tableID: "datatable1",
     //order: [[ 1, 'asc' ]],
     sourceDataUrl: ApiPath + "Dashboard/GetRegulatoryTable?Type=" + type + "&Subject=" + subject + "&Month=" + month + "&Year=" + year,
     autoColHeader: {
         enable: "false",
         colHead: ["Update ID", "Month", "Year", "Subject", "Description", "Document Path", "Created By", "Created Date"]
     },
     disableColindex: "[]",
});
```

generates a table in your HTML - but it almost certainly does it in an asynchronous manner (given that `sourceDataUrl` is mentioned).

As such, when:

```
if ($("#datatable1").html().indexOf("No data available", 1) > 1) { //here its throwing an error
```

executes, `GenerateTable` is not yet finished its work (part of which is to generate the table with ID of `datatable1`).

To solve this, you need to delay executing the `if` statement until `GenerateTable` has finished its work. `GenerateTable` likely has some form of callback (e.g. `onsuccess`) to indicate that the table has been inserted into the HTML.